# Run script from .profile

Tags: bash, alias, profile

I want to put all the environment variables and aliases into a separate file.
Here is my `~/.profile`

```
/c/webProj/myprofile
```

Here is the `/c/webProj/myprofile` :

```
PATH=$PATH:./node_modules/.bin
alias gs="git status"
```

Why it doesn’t work?
The alias has not present and PATH is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a dot like this

```
. /c/webProj/myprofile
```